# Tiempo de escritura jquery

Tags: jquery, entrada

Tengo una duda y no he podido encontrar solución.

Lo que pasa que estoy usando un código de barra en un `input`, pero este `input` también tiene una función de buscar datos en tiempo real(ajax) en la base de datos, lo que trato de hacer que cuando el código de barra escriba y es muy rápido, mi función de buscar datos no salte.

Necesito algo que detecte el tiempo de escritura, si es muy rápido solo escriba pero si es lento busque.

Muchas gracias saludos.

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
      //al momento de escribir busca productos
      $("#buscar").keyup(function() {
        mostrarproductos();
      });

    }

    function mostrarproductos() {
      var buscartx = $('#buscar').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "vender/mostrarproductos",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          buscar: buscartx
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {
          var registro = eval(respuesta);
          var contar = 0;
          var html;
          for (var i = 0; i < registro.length; i++) {
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td id=" + registro[i]["codigo2"] + ">" + registro[i]["codigo2"] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + registro[i]["nombre"] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + registro[i]["stock"] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + registro[i]["precio"] + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            contar += 1;
          };;
          if (contar > 0) {
            $("#tbody-01").html(html);
            // $("#resultx").text("Resultado encontrados: " + contar);
          } else {
            $("#table-01 tbody tr").remove();
            // $("#resultx").text("Resultado encontrados: 0");
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<input id="buscar" name="buscar" 
  class="form-control text-uppercase mx-1 texbox_min"
  type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
```

Comment: Hola Daniel! intentaremos ayudarte. Puedes poner algo de código para poder basarnos en algo?

Comment: Y con escritura a que te refieres? el tiempo que se tarda en escribir en el `input`?

Comment: esta listo, agregue el código disculpen soy nuevo en esto de preguntar en esta pagina :)

Comment: @Txema si eso mismo lo que ando buscando :)

Comment: pues mira, haz [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sabras mas o menos como funciona y ganaras tu primera medalla. luego mirate [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y ya estas listo !

Comment: Y una pregunta, que maneras tienes de escribir? una es automática( escáner o algo parecido) y la otra por teclado?

Comment: @Txema hola de nuevo, el lector de codigo, funciona como un teclado aparte, al terminar de leer el codigo de barra manda un enter pero las dos forman serian como decirlo manual, aunque si el lector es automatico. por eso necesito una forma de calcular el tiempo de escritura para que no funcione la funcion de "mostrarproductos"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es poner un contador de tiempo cuando escribe y al seguir escribiendo, este contador se va reiniciando. Solo al finalizar el tiempo se haría la llamada.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tiempoescritura;
    // iniciamos el timer
    $("#buscar").keyup(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(tiempoescritura);
        if (e.keyCode == 13){ // Si se presiona enter no se ejecutará la función
          return true;
        }
        // he puesto 1s, podrías poner el valor que quieras
        tiempoescritura = setTimeout(mostrarproductos, 1000);
    });
    // borramos el timer
    $("#buscar").keydown(function() {
        clearTimeout(tiempoescritura);
    });
    function mostrarproductos(){
      console.log("He dejado de escribir!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="buscar" name="buscar" class="form-control text-uppercase mx-1 texbox_min" type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
```

Si ejecutas y pruebas verás el console.log() al dejar de escribir durante 1s.

Comment: muchas gracias, tratare de adaptarla a mi código :)

Comment: No lo acabo de entender, pones un timeout a 1s y cuando pase 1s, que llame a la función?

Comment: @Txema mientras la tecla está pulsada, el timeout se limpia. Al levantar la tecla, el timeout se inicia haciendo una cuenta atrás de 1s. Al pasar este segundo se hace la llamada a "mostrarproductos" (que sería el ajax)

Comment: @DanielP. Si te sirve no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta, gracias.

Comment: pero va a ejecutar el ajax si o si, lo haga rápido o lo haga lento no? Según el OP, 'si es muy rápido solo escriba pero si es lento busque'. Es decir, el 'automático' no debería buscar

Comment: @Txema si, la función sigue funcionando pero creo que colando una condición, por decir si viene con un enter no siga ejecutándose eso trata de hacer ahora :)

Comment: @DanielP. si viene con un enter? quieres decir que si la última tecla pulsada es un enter, que no ejecute el ajax?

Comment: @DanielP. He agregado los cambios tal que si la última tecla pulsada es un enter, no llamaría a la función del ajax

Comment: gracias por la modificacion, tambien le agrege la condicion y me funciono, voy a probar tu forma si es mas funcional, te pasaste con la ayuda